# how `if` chain comparing integers against a value can be rewritten with `match`?

Tags: rust

```
fn test_if_else(c: i32) {
    if c > 0 {
        println!("The number {} is greater than zero", c);
    } else if c < 0 {
        println!("The number {} is less then zero", c);
    } else {
         println!("the number {} is equal to zero", c);
}
```

here's what happened to me

```
 match c {
    0 => println!("the number {} is equal to zero", c),
    0..infinity => println!("The number {} is greater than zero", c),
    _ => println!("the number {} is equal to zero", c)
 }
```

but it doesn't work with 'infinity'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just need to use an open range `0..`:

```rust
fn test_if_else(c: i32) {
    match c {
        0 => println!("the number {} is equal to zero", c),
        0.. => println!("The number {} is greater than zero", c),
        _ => println!("the number {} is lesser than zero", c),
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b7e4cd07bbe15a50f5b4d7a585d21a88)

Comment: Better to replace `_` with `..0`, but unfortunately it's not stable :(

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this with an `if c>0` guard, which is a little more flexible.

```
fn test_if_else(c: i32) {
    match c {
        0 => println!("the number {} is equal to zero", c),
        c if c > 0 => println!("The number {} is greater than zero", c),
        _ => println!("the number {} is lesser than zero", c),
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that guards do not work with exhaustiveness checking, if you do no use a wildcard.